# How to update the Samsung Evo 850 firmware?

Tags: firmware

I bought a Samsung Evo 850 250G for a Lenovo T400.

I could only install Ubuntu 16.04 on it for the fourth try because the installer freezed and this random freezing kept up after the OS was installed.

I read that Samsung Evo 840 had issues on Linux in ~2014, but we are in 2017 and this is an Evo 850!

I think I will try to install a windows, update the firmware of the SSD, then install Ubuntu again.

**Question**: how can I update the firmware of the Evo 850?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You download Samsung Magician Software and then click Firmware upgrade and upgrade the firmware if necessary. The link for software and firmware at Samsung homepage:

[Samsung SSD](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html)

Comment: later it turned out ubuntu 16 doesn't supports evo 850 by default, needed to use ubuntu 14

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, here is what worked for me to update my EVO 850 from firmware EMT01B6Q to EMT02B6Q.

After downloading either the Windows .iso or the Mac .iso with the update from Samsung (`https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Samsung_SSD_Firmware`), you can run the magician binary on your linux machine by setting up mount points and extracting as described here:

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Samsung_SSD_Firmware

This worked while the disk was mounted on `/`

(I did take the small precaution of quitting all open desktop applications, but I stayed in the MATE graphic environment. I also diverged from the instructions by not creating my directories in `/tmp`, which shouldn't--and didn't--matter, and I used different names for some of the directories.)

I should mention that although these instructions come from a Gentoo Linux resource, they seem to be quite distro-independent. For the record I used Ubuntu MATE 22.04 running on a Mac Pro (early 2009) with the EVO 850 physicaly on an adapter in the first drive bay.

Note the files that matter are these, in /root/magician or the iso image:

```
$ ls -l fumagician/
total 4956`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rdh rdh     240 Jul  1 08:41 DSRD.enc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rdh rdh 2319776 Jul  1 08:41 EMT02B6Q.enc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rdh rdh 2742032 Jul  1 08:41 fumagician
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rdh rdh     290 Jul  1 08:41 fumagician.sh
```

As I alluded to above, Samsung offers both a Windows and a Mac version of the iso. You can use either one, since these files are bit-for-bit identical on the two versions.

The alternative is to burn the .iso and boot from it -- supposedly the official way from Samsung, though they (as expected) offer no instructions explaining that that is the case. I did not try this.

There seems to be a consensus out there that the only reliable way to update firmware on an EVO-series SSD is to reformat it to NTFS and run the Magician software on Windows. That is apparantly not so, at least not in the case of the now-venerable EV0 850.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ISO updater:

- https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/
- in FIRMWARE download "SATA SSD-850 EVO Firmware"
- put it on a USB drive using SUSE Image Writer or dd or etcher
- boot it and update the 850 EVO.

If when scanning, it skips to proposing a reboot, it means that the SSD is already up to date.

note: I did the update from version EMT01B6Q to EMT02B6 and there was no data loss.